# Is V/F maintained constant even in field oriented control or vector control drive of PMSM motors?

Tags: inverter, induction-motor, vfd, pmsm, vector-control

I understand that in scalar control V/F is maintained constant below rated speed, as Vector control drive is also a variable frequency drive, I would like to know whether V/F is maintained constant below rated speed in field oriented control of PMSM motors as well, as I don't see it from the equations.

Could anyone show me through the vector control equations?

Comment: Yes this is still linear above the stall speed until motor inductance near max RPM reduces efficiency.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ug/pmsm-field-weakening-control.html